# import csv into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, import

I am facing difficulty importing a csv file to python from my desktop. It seems that the file or the location is not being recognized while reading.
Have tried several different methods to import, but every time it gives the same error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/uditasingh/Desktop/Analysis/monthly_visits.csv'
```

for the code:

```
import csv
cr = csv.reader(open("/Users/uditasingh/Desktop/Analysis/monthly_visits.csv","rb"))
```

I have obtained the path of the csv file from the file 'properties'.
Don't understand what seems to be going wrong.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Trust the error - the file probably doesn't exist. You can remove the

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that it searches for the `Users` directory in the code's working dir and obviously can't find it. Try to use the full path, ie 'C:/Users/......`.

Answer (score 0):

try to write

> cr = csv.reader(open("\Users\uditasingh\Desktop\Analysis....))